# What happens to a company's negative value property if it is liquidated?

Tags: united-kingdom, liability, bankruptcy

What happens to annoying burdensome assets during a company's liquidation?

Perhaps a company owns [a mine filled with deadly arsenic trioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Mine)  waiting to break out into the environment, or something more boring like a [useless grade A listed building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Peter%27s_Seminary,_Cardross) that must be maintained.

These aren't just debts that be cancelled. So what's meant to happen?

Comment: At least in the US, the mortgage would lapse and the property would be sold at auction. If it was paid for, the taxes would lapse and the state would seize it and sell it at auction for the back taxes. It really depends on a lot of factors like ownership structure, how the business is dissolved, etc. I think this is too broad as written.

Answer (score 3):

In the U.K., [bankruptcy law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankruptcy_in_the_United_Kingdom) applies to individuals and partnerships, while the [U.K. insolvency law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_insolvency_law) applies to companies. In an insolvency proceeding, there is administration (the rough equivalent of a Chapter 11 Bankruptcy in the U.S.)or a liquidation (the rough equivalent fo a Chapter 7 Bankruptcy in the U.S.).

In administration, the administrator of the company renegotiates debt payments so that carrying costs of office buildings can be brought to less than rental income, if possible, and if not, or if it is a liquidation in the first place, sells the building at auction to the highest bidder and stiffs unpaid creditors if this is not enough to pay them all according to priority and pro rata within each priority ranking. Simple.

Negative value property is trickier. Sometimes someone can be paid to take it over (this happens often with depleted oil and gas wells that have to be plugged), if there are sufficient funds to do so. The administrator may instead [disclaim the property](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/45/part/IX/chapter/IV/crossheading/disclaimer-of-onerous-property/2006-04-03).

> A disclaimer under this section— (a)operates so as to determine, as
>   from the date of the disclaimer, the rights, interests and liabilities
>   of the bankrupt and his estate in or in respect of the property
>   disclaimed, and (b)discharges the trustee from all personal liability
>   in respect of that property as from the commencement of his
>   trusteeship, but does not, except so far as is necessary for the
>   purpose of releasing the bankrupt, the bankrupt’s estate and the
>   trustee from any liability, affect the rights or liabilities of any
>   other person.. . . (5)Any person sustaining loss or damage in
>   consequence of the operation of a disclaimer under this section is
>   deemed to be a creditor of the bankrupt to the extent of the loss or
>   damage and accordingly may prove for the loss or damage as a
>   bankruptcy debt.

Basically, a court decides what to do with it. If no one claims it and it has been disclaimed by the administrator, it [escheats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escheat) to the Crown (i.e. the U.K. state) as it would if a decedent's estate with no creditors or heirs.

This disclaimer process is similar to the process in Australia described in the answer by @DaleM and has the same name in U.K. law as it does in Australia.

> Escheat can still occur in England and Wales, if a person is made
>   bankrupt or a corporation is liquidated. Usually this means that all
>   the property held by that person is 'vested in' (transferred to) the
>   Official Receiver or Trustee in Bankruptcy. However, it is open to the
>   Receiver or Trustee to refuse to accept that property by disclaiming
>   it. It is relatively common for a trustee in bankruptcy to disclaim
>   freehold property which may give rise to a liability, for example the
>   common parts of a block of flats owned by the bankrupt would
>   ordinarily pass to the trustee to be realised in order to pay his
>   debts, but the property may give the landlord an obligation to spend
>   money for the benefit of lessees of the flats. 
>   **The bankruptcy of the
>   original owner means that the freehold is no longer the bankrupt's
>   legal property, and the disclaimer destroys the freehold estate, so
>   that the land ceases to be owned by anyone and effectively escheats to
>   become land held by the Crown in [demesne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demesne#Royal_demesne).** This situation affects a few
>   hundred properties each year.
>
> **Although such escheated property is owned by the Crown, it is not part
>   of the Crown Estate, unless the Crown (through the Crown Estate
>   Commissioners) 'completes' the escheat, by taking steps to exert
>   rights as owner.** However, usually, in the example given above, the
>   tenants of the flats, or their mortgagees would exercise their rights
>   given by the Insolvency Act 1986 to have the freehold property
>   transferred to them. This is the main difference between escheat and
>   bona vacantia, as in the latter, a grant takes place automatically,
>   with no need to 'complete' the transaction.

Thus, the toxic property would escheat to the Crown, but not the [Crown Estate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Estate) (defined below, which would not claim it since it has no value) and no one else would claim it. So, it would be technically owned by the government but not administered by anyone, unless the government affirmatively decided to do so.

> The Crown Estate is a collection of lands and holdings in the United
>   Kingdom belonging to the British monarch as a corporation sole, making
>   it the "Sovereign's public estate", which is neither government
>   property nor part of the monarch's private estate. As a result of this
>   arrangement, the sovereign is not involved with the management or
>   administration of the estate, and exercises only very limited control
>   of its affairs. Instead, the estate's extensive portfolio is
>   overseen by a semi-independent, incorporated public body headed by the
>   Crown Estate Commissioners, who exercise "the powers of ownership" of
>   the estate, although they are not "owners in their own right". The
>   revenues from these hereditary possessions have been placed by the
>   monarch at the disposition of Her Majesty's Government in exchange for
>   relief from the responsibility to fund the Civil Government. These
>   revenues thus proceed directly to Her Majesty's Treasury, for the
>   benefit of the British nation. The Crown Estate is formally
>   accountable to the Parliament of the United Kingdom, where it is
>   legally mandated to make an annual report to the sovereign, a copy of
>   which is forwarded to the House of Commons.
>
> The Crown Estate is one of the largest property managers in the United
>   Kingdom, overseeing property worth £12 billion, with urban properties
>   valued at £9.1 billion representing the majority of the estate by
>   value. These include a large number of properties in central London,
>   but the estate also controls 792,000 ha (1,960,000 acres) of
>   agricultural land and forest and more than half of the UK's foreshore,
>   and retains various other traditional holdings and rights, including
>   Ascot Racecourse and Windsor Great Park. Naturally occurring gold and
>   silver in the UK, collectively known as "Mines Royal", are managed by
>   the Crown Estate and leased to mining operators.

Also, while not strictly on point, the [Environment Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Agency) in the U.K. may criminally prosecute people who were involved in breaking the environmental laws in question, if they are still living.

(In Colorado, where I live, most toxic mines date to the 19th century, were abandoned, everyone who was personally involved with them is dead, and the state and federal EPA try to clean them up as funds become available, sometimes making the problem worse due to unexpected mishaps that occur in the cleanup process.)

Answer (score 2):

In Australia, Division 7A of Part 5.6 of the [Corporations Act](http://www6.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdb/au/legis/cth/consol_act/ca2001172/), titled "Disclaimer of Onerous Property" deals with this.

In essence, it allows the liquidator to abandon any claim to the property on behalf of the company. The process is:

- the liquidator gives notice of the intent (s568A)
- anyone with an interest in the disclaimed property has 14 days to apply to the court to stop the disclaimer (s568B). If they do, the court can set it aside provided that it would cause the aggrieved person "prejudice that is grossly out of proportion to the prejudice that setting aside the disclaimer would cause the company's creditors" and make other orders.
- If there is no objection or the court decides to allow the disclaimer anyway the company's interest in the property ends. Anyone aggrieved by this becomes an unsecured creditor of the company to the extent of their loss (s568D).
- With the leave of the court, a person may apply for the disclaimer to be set aside if it was unreasonable for them to have applied beforehand (s568E).
- The court will then dispose of the property by ordering a person to become the owner (s568F). A "person entitled to the property" or "a person to whom it seems to the Court appropriate for the property to be vested or delivered" or "a trustee" for one of those persons. For real property, this will probably be the government who is responsible for the land it sits on.